# Call adb monkey from Java Application

Tags: android, adb

I'm making a Java application that I want to call the adb monkey tester for an android package. From the cmd, I was managed to call it but from the Java application, I wasn't. Any ideas? Find my code below.

Cmd command that works:

```
adb -s 079d35918ec8c84b shell monkey -p com.zte.bamachaye -v 1000
```

In my Java code, i have the code below, which when I run the process never finish. It stuck there and the app is still on the smartphone

```
ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("adb","-s", "079d35918ec8c84b","shell monkey","-p", packageName, "-v", "500");
              Process pc2 = pb2.start();
              pc2.waitFor();
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ProcessBuilder pb2 = new ProcessBuilder("adb","-s", "079d35918ec8c84b","shell", "monkey -p " + packageName + " -v 500");`

Comment: OMG really? Thank you very much for your help. I didn't know that i have to separate the shell from the monkey. Now it's working :)